# Using mod_rewrite to hide all PHP extensions (incl. subdirectories)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am trying to hide the php extension at the end of a url for a site using mod_rewrite. The site has the following content:

```
/index.php
/news.php
/about/index.php
/about/contact.php
```

I would like the following to work:

```
http://domain.com/news
http://domain.com/about
http://domain.com/about/contact
```

Right now I am using the following rewrite, but it isn't working for sub-directories

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

TIA.

Comment: Options +Multiviews would do the trick also, but I do not like this setting, not very securized

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right place for this.

Answer (score 1):

### Preamble

First off, this post is to answer the question posed.  I also include some more security considerations for your benefit, and for anyone else's benefit who thinks that "security by obfuscation" is pointless (If that were true, there would be no need to obfuscate passwords...)  I feel bad for all of those who bash the question, and even more, for your employers, I suggest you spend more time in learning about how to secure a site.  The OWASP site is a good resource (https://www.owasp.org).

For those of you who question this, or would like to know a little more about security, please see **Security Considerations** below.

### The Solution

The best solution that I have found is to make it appear that your server-side technology specific files don't exist.  For example, when the hacker gets redirected on .php files, and 404 on .jsp files, you are obviously using PHP.  What you need to do is make requests to .php look the same as requests to .jsp, .cfn etc.

This can easily be done by using your sites welcome file and directories.  For example:

You will need to set your site directories up like:

- /index.php
- /news/index.php
- /about/index.php
- /about/contact/index.php

Also, in your apache configuration file (or .htaccess), you went to set the **DirectoryIndex** for your site:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Once you have finished setting this up each of these can be accessed by (These would also work with trailing slashes):

```
http://www.yoursite.com/
http://www.yoursite.com/news
http://www.yoursite.com/about
http://www.yoursite.com/about/contact
```

Now that this is done, you can set up the whole point of this exorcise: hiding the fact that you are using PHP.  You simply have to hide the fact that you are using PHP, this is simply done by making index.php act the same as index.cfm, index.py, index.jsp etc... would on your site: return a 404 because they don't exist...
The rewrite block would look something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ default [R=404,L]
```

Obviously, this can be done with other server-side technologies such as ColdFusion, Python, Java, ASP.NET (Heaven forbid you are using Apache2 instead of IIS ;) ) etc...

### Other Considerations

Obviously a secure site uses a well rounded approach with many facets.  Please don't take this post as saying that all you need to do to secure your site is to obfuscate what technology you are using.  Clearly, hiding what technology you are using won't fix the security issues in that given technology.  This post simply claims that it is a good tool to add to the set.  You will need to apply other layers of security at each layer of the application/solution to have a truly secure site.

Granted, obfuscating the technology will not fool the best of hackers and bots.  It is best to keep the mindset of "if it can be accessed, it can be hacked. Period.".  The only truly secure solution is to cut the wires to the server.  The battle between hacker and developer is a never-ending one.  It is exactly that too, a battle.  You could liken it a lot to Sun Tzu's "Art Of War".  A well working site works against you in terms of security.

The point being - any information a hacker can use to exploit you, he/she will.  Therefore, something as significant as knowing the server-side technology being used to render the pages would be of great use to hackers, they can exploit weaknesses in the specific technology.  This means that hiding extensions has a **very valid** purpose, in keeping the hackers guessing.  Instead of just focusing on one technology, the hacker has to guess which technology is being used before they can exploit any technology specific weakness.  The bottom line: the less the hacker knows, the better.

### Response Headers

Many server-side technologies will have specific header response information associated to them, such as the cookie that identifies the session ID (like JSESSIONID in Java).  After obfuscating the file extension, you will need to look into renaming the header variables used for session and other parameters to something unique to your application.  Without scrubbing the response headers, hiding what extension you are using is pointless.

### XSS and SQL Injection

A bigger threat to DB driven applications is Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) and even worse, SQL Injection.  If you are trying to secure your site - I would spend some time into looking into solutions for these as well.  Look into network level resource injection as well (Such as spoofing DNS entries to make a site look like it is on your domain).

Enjoy and good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

http://www.interactivetools.com/docs/cmsbuilder/file_extensions.html

Comment: Does not work, URIs with files in sub-directories (/about/contact) return a 404.

Answer (score 0):

hiding php extensions is **useless**.
there is absolutely no point in such a thing.

if you want "human-readable" or "seo-friendly" urls, i will do not much help.
in any other case it is going to be just useless.

instead of having separate PHP script for the each page, try to learn more and implement some sort of Content-Management System, using just one PHP script to display couple pages of the same kind, by retrieving the actual content from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the slash at the end if it's present. This implies copy paste of your rule (= with and without the slash (didn't find another way)):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if there's a slash, remove it:
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You may need to add `DirectorySlash Off` to prevent a redirect-tennis match between the both.

Comment: You're right... if I didn't put these 2 RewriteCond `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`. Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```